# pod installs swift 2.3 frameworks instead of swift 3 code

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods

hi i am trying to install some frameworks using cocoapods and when i run 'pod install' it installs swift 2.3 frameworks which are not supported in swift 3

For Example

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'

pod 'BarcodeScanner'
target 'WhiskyBazar' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
 use_frameworks!


 # Pods for WhiskyBazar

 target 'WhiskyBazarTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
 end

 target 'WhiskyBazarUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end
end
```

when i run the above, it always installs barcode scanner version 1.0.0 which is supported in swift 2.3. But the latest version of barcode scanner is barcode scanner 2.0.0 which supports swift 3. please advice what changes i have to make in my project to install the latest version of the pod which supports swift 3.0

Comment: then use `pod 'BarcodeScanner' , '> 1.0'` AND set command as pod install

Comment: share the library link

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Cocoapods?

Answer (score 1):

you should try

pod 'BarcodeScanner', '~> 2.0'

Answer (score 0):

In the pod file,

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'WhiskyBazar' do
      # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
     use_frameworks!

   pod 'BarcodeScanner','~>2.0'

     # Pods for WhiskyBazar

     target 'WhiskyBazarTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for testing
     end

    target 'WhiskyBazarUITests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for testing
    end
end
```

& give path of podfile on terminal,

cd path/->

pod install